# Plotting a 3-dimensional graph by increasing the size of the points

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis, scatter-plot

Currently I have a plot that look like this.

[image: Photo of my plot (I want to plot this in 3D)]

1. How do I increase the size of each point by the count? In other words, if a certain point has 9 counts, how do I increase it so that it is bigger than another point with only 2 counts?
2. If you look closely, I think there are overlaps (one point has both grey and orange circles). How do I make it so there's a clear difference?

In case you have no idea what I mean by "Plotting a 3-dimensional graph by increasing the size of the points", this below is what I mean, where the z-axis is the count

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer doesn't really answer the question straight up, but please consider this multivariate solution seaborn has:

The syntax is way easier to write than using matplotlib.

```
seaborn.jointplot(
    data = data,
    x = x_name,
    y = y_name,
    hue = label_name
)
```

And voila! You should get something that looks like this

[image]

See: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html

Comment: Thank you. The syntax is indeed easier to use haha. Although this is a way more elegant answer and I will definitely be using this, someone else has answered this question already.

Answer (score 0):

Using `matplotlib` library you could iterate on your data and count it (some example below).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate Data

N = 100
l_bound = -10
u_bound = 10

s_0 = 40
array = np.random.randint(l_bound, u_bound, (N, 2))

# Plot it

points, counts = np.unique(array, axis = 0, return_counts = True)

for point_, count_ in zip(points, counts):
    plt.scatter(point_[0], point_[1], c = np.random.randint(0, 3), s = s_0* count_**2, vmin = 0, vmax = 2)
    
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoK5m.png)

You can probably do the same with Plotly to have something fancier and closer to your second picture.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, however, it doesn't work on my dataset. I'm currently using a pandas dataset. 

Please check out the other answers, I think they are pretty elegant and cool too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x_name = 'x_name'
y_name = 'y_name'
z_name = 'z_name'


scatter_data = pd.DataFrame(data[[x_name, y_name, z_name]].value_counts())

scatter_data.reset_index(inplace=True)


plt.scatter(
    scatter_data.loc[:, x_name], 
    scatter_data.loc[:, y_name],
    s=scatter_data.loc[:, 0],
    c=scatter_data.loc[:, z_name]
)
```

The thing is that the reason why your scatter plot looks like this is because every point which is at (1, 1) or (0,1) is overlapping.

With the plt.scatter argument (s=), you can specify the size of the points. If you print scatter_data, it is a "group by" clause with the count of each of the indexes.

[image]

It should look something like this, with column `0` being the count.

[image]

It should look something like the above.

Comment: Thanks! Although, I have to point out something. At the top, you wrote z_name = 'z_name'. I assume you mean the z_name is the z_axis. However, the z_name is not the z_axis, just some other grouping. The correct z_axis should be the value_counts column from scatter_data.value_counts().